# Symfony 3 Asset() not finding the web folder

Tags: php, symfony

I am upgrading from Symfony 2.0 to Symfony and on my localhost it can't find the web folder.

Instead of pulling up web/css/main.css I get /css/main.css

Is there a setting somewhere that is getting over ridden?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more precise. What exactly are you doing? What happens? But what did you expect? Do you get error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add:

```
assets_base_urls:
        http:  [/web/] 
        ssl:   [/web/]
```

To the config.yml under templating